# Tag sets and tag name consistency

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag sets have introduced a way in which identical tag names are associated across SOFU & SX sites.  We've got a few inconsistencies with SO, e.g., while [excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel) and  [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), are the user and programmer questions associated with the well-known piece of software and match, [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) and [msword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msword) 
don't.

There's at least some value to having the same tags used across sites, since it makes it easier to track related questions across sites using tag sets.  Is it worth trying to do this?  If so, how should we go about it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm of the opinion we have whichever master tag works best for us / is used the most here / etc and just create synonyms for anything that falls in to the situation you are describing (only if a synonym is relevant and correct, of course).

In fact, if you look at the [synonyms](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-word/synonyms) for [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) and you'll see that [msword](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msword) is already a synonym, so really we are already using the same tag as SO.

Further to this, check out the [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/msword/synonyms) for [msword](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/msword) on SO - and you'll see they have [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) as a synonym already.

Both sites already have the same tag group in place, so I don't see a real issue, and any other tags that could do with a similar grouping just need synonyms creating.

### Update

I just added `msword` for all sites on to my tag set, and was getting both SO [msword](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/msword) questions and SU [msword](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msword) question in the feed. So it seems to be doing the job it should be doing.

Comment: Ah, tag sets take synonyms into account - this is good to know.  There's still some residual value to consistency across sites, to do with people finding it easier to se what is going on with various sites.  But I think this tells me the answer: it's not worth trying to do.

Comment: @Charles It's not really "not worth trying"; it's just a different implimentation from your post - I do think it's probably worth trying to make sites have similar groupings of tags via synonyms, but renaming things across every site so they all use the same master tag would be a bit overkill, unessecary, and would probably face strong local opposition.