# Rename tag [tortoise-svn] to [tortoisesvn] to be consistent with other stack* sites

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms

I world like to propose tha the tag [tortoise-svn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tortoise-svn) is renamed to [tortoisesvn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn), because that is the tag that is used on stackowerflow.

That makes the cross site feature tagging better.

Comment: Why rename, why not just create a synonym to link `tortoisesvn` to `tortoise-svn`? Once linked by a synonym, [I understand](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1691/tag-sets-and-tag-name-consistency/1692#1692) that the end result is the same, and personally I find the hyphenated versions more pleasing on the eye.

Comment: I haven't seen tag synonyms before. After quickly searching around, i think synonyms is a god solution.

Answer (score 3):

That's fine -- but what about

[tortoise-hg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tortoise-hg)
[tortoise-git](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tortoise-git)

Should those also be changed?

Comment: After reading about tag synonyms, I think that synonyms are the best solution.

Comment: I don't know if tag synonyms are cross site, but if not, i think it should be considered. After thinking about it a bit more, Cross site tags, can give som problems, especially for 3 letter acronyms (eg, ASP = Aplication Service Provider or (.ASP files (pre ASP.NET))